# Visual Studio Code color not working when using python types

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using the new python syntax to describe what types my methods return e.g.,: `def method(unpacked_message: dict) -> dict:`

This seems to break the vscode color scheme

[image]

Expected colors:

[image]

Environment and vs code extensions:

- Python 3.6.9 on ubuntu
- ms-python.python v2020.11.371526539
- tht13.python: Python for VS code v0.2.3
- magicstack.magicpython: MagicPython v1.1.0

The code runs flawlessly. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: which color is off? the `retrocompatibility` is colored as a variable because the word `for` is in front

Comment: @rioV8 I added "normal" colors in post

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem you described.

Reason: The Syntax Highlighting style provided by the extension "`Python for VSCode`" is different from the extension "`Python`".

Solution: Please disable the extension "`Python for VSCode`".

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Not work here. I disable Python for VSCode but still types and other keywords are not colored

Comment: FYI for anyone looking here: the "Python for VSCode" extension is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a temporary solution.

It's a way to create a meaningless def _(): pass.

```
def function() -> str:
   def _():
     pass

   return 'Hello World!'
```

or

```
def function() -> str:
   # def _():

   return 'Hello World!'
```