# Python type hint on return of function lets vs studio code no longer green color comment

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

For the following code

```
def sum2(a: int, b:int) -> int:
    # test
    return a + b

print(sum2(2,3))
```

once there is `-> int`, the comment part `# test` is no longer in green color in my VS code IDE 1.76.2. What is the reason for it and how to fix it? Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in VSCode 1.76.2

Comment: mine is also 1.76.2, maybe some extension issue?

Comment: found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65108382/visual-studio-code-color-not-working-when-using-python-types, disable is not enough, i need to uninstall it. then it works. this question can be closed.