# Visual Studio Code giving no syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently opened VS Code for the first time in a while, only to see that the code I was working on has absolutely no form of color organization. I'm not very experienced with VS Code, so it could be a simple fix, but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like, as well as the extensions I have:
[image: screenshot of described VS Code issue]

I have tried changing the color scheme as well as uninstalling extensions, reloading VS Code, then installing the extensions again but none of that has worked.

Comment: Not sure, why `.py` file is saved as a `.txt` format file. As a test, can you try to `save as type: All files (*)` with `.py` extension and open it in vscode?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I tried that and it made no change unfortunately. Also, what do you mean by ".py file is saved as a .txt format file"? I don't see anywhere where something is saved as a .txt file.

Comment: I mean, your `.py` file is detecting as text formatted file and not sure about the reason. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119013/8353711)?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I see, thank you for the clarification. I have seen that solution, however "Python for VSCode" is depreciated and no longer available, so I know that isn't the issue.

Comment: try it with the `Default Light+` theme, you have selected a High Contrast Theme and syntax highlighting reduces contrast

Answer (score 0):

I'm no entirely sure what the exact issue is, but I think that I deleted some files or folders or something for VS Code. Uninstalling the reinstalling VS Code has fixed the issue entirely. I apologize for an unnecessary post.